# Google maps driving directions: Substitution of javascript values?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Somewhere at stackoverflow I found this (slightly modified by me) to render basic driving instructions from Google maps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps API v3 Directions Example</title> 
   <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=de"></script>
</head> 
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;"> 
   <div style="width: 600px;">
     <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; float: left;"></div> 
     <div id="panel" style="width: 500px; float: left;"></div> 
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom:7,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

     var request = {
       origin: 'An der Alster 1, Hamburg', 
       destination: 'Albada 1, Cala Llombards, Mallorca',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     });
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I have modified the example a bit to fit my Kindle screen - now, as my JavaScript is really bad - how do I update this to have two text boxes at the top to ask for `origin` and `destination`, and maybe two radio boxes to let me select the value for `travelMode` (`DRIVING`and `WALKING`)?

Thanks!

---

Full copy-and-paste answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps API v3 Directions Example</title> 
   <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=de"></script>
</head> 
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;"> 

Start:<input type="text" id="start"><br>
Ende: <input type="text" id="end"><br>
<div>
<select id="mode" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="DRIVING">Auto</option>
  <option value="WALKING">zu Fuß</option>
</select><br>
<input type="button" value="Los" onclick="calcRoute();">
</div>
<br>

   <div style="width: 600px;">
     <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; float: left;"></div> 
     <div id="panel" style="width: 400px; float: left;"></div> 
   </div>


   <script type="text/javascript"> 

     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom:7,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

     var request = {
       origin: '', 
       destination: '',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     });

     function calcRoute() {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Just because I found this funny: Viewed 1006 times, earned me the "popular question" badge - zero votes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below markup and code which takes input from textboxes and also the travelling mode from a dropdownbox-

**HTML-**

```
Start:<input type="text" id="start">
End:<input type="text" id="end">
<div>
<strong>Mode of Travel: </strong>
<select id="mode" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
  <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
  <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
  <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Javascript-**

```
function calcRoute() {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Everyone else, futre me etc: For the full copy-and-paste HTML see above.